# Wildfly, fat jar and jndi-registration

Tags: maven, jar, wildfly

When I build a fat jar with my ejb and dependencies, all the dependent libs/jars are unpacked, and when deployed to wildfly, jodi-registration is performed, and entries like

```
    java:global/template-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies/ReceptionService
```

are reported on the console. I can then add a module dependency to my war-project manifest and use the ejb.

When I build the exact same ejb using one-jar plugin, the dependent libraries are not unpacked, and jndi-registration is not performed. Hence the ejb is not reachable.

From what I can se the jar files are otherwise similar, and it seems wildfly behaves different depending if included jars are unpacked or not. Is this so, and why? Or does the one-jar plugin create a fat jar that is different in some way that I have not figured out?

The pom.xml is listed below, with the one-jar config that I use commented out:

```
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>

            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>assemble-all</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Includes the runtime dependencies -->
        <!--
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.dstovall</groupId>
            <artifactId>onejar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <configuration>
                        <attachToBuild>true</attachToBuild>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>one-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        -->
```

Comment: You'd need to inspect the JAR's to see the differences. WildFly shouldn't care though. I've used the maven-shade-plugin plugin before and it hasn't been an issue.

Comment: Yes, hence the question: Does Wildfly treat jars differently if they contain packed dependency jars (as when packaged with one-jar) than when dependency jars are unpacked, as with maven-assembly-plugin (or shade-plugin)? This is the most substantial difference to be seen when inspecting the jars. There might be others, that I have not discovered yet. The shade plugin does not include jars, but unpack the classes in the jars. And the ejbs are jndi-registered. It is when jars are included "as is" no jndi-registration is performed.

Comment: So you're packing JAR's in your JAR? If that's the case then yeah that won't work. There's is no default concept for a JAR to contain other JAR's.

Comment: weird behaviour for a plugin then ... anyway, shading does unpack the jars, I got it working for a simple hello world setup, but ran into more dependency problems when deploying the real-life ejbs. ear is probably the way to go.